# How to animate to wrap_content?

Tags: android, android-animation

Is it possible to animate using `ValueAnimator` to `wrap_content`? this only seems to work with constant values.

```
public static void valueAnimate(final View obj, int from, int to, Interpolator interpolator, long duration, long delay){

    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(from, to);
    anim.setInterpolator(interpolator == null ? DEFAULT_INTERPOLATOR : interpolator);
    anim.setDuration(duration);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            obj.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
            obj.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    anim.setStartDelay(delay);
    anim.start();
}
```

How could I pass a the `to` parameter as `wrap_content`?

```
Animator.valueAnimate(mapUtilsContainer, CURR_MAPUTILC_H, 800, OVERSHOOT, 300, 0);
```

Comment: Have you tried animateLayoutChanges?   https://proandroiddev.com/the-little-secret-of-android-animatelayoutchanges-e4caab2fddec

Comment: Yes, not what I'm looking for. This is playing with the layout params and the default animation. I need to use `ValuAnimation`

Comment: are you trying to expand a view that originally hidden?

Comment: @noahutz  Yes, it's a `RelativeLayout` that will toggle between 0 and wrap_content

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this. Pass a view that is set initially to gone.

```
public static void expand(final View view) {
    view.measure(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final int targetHeight = view.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Set initial height to 0 and show the view
    view.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getMeasuredHeight(), targetHeight);
    anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = (int) (targetHeight * animation.getAnimatedFraction());
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        }
    });
    anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            // At the end of animation, set the height to wrap content
            // This fix is for long views that are not shown on screen
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        }
    });
    anim.start();
}
```

Comment: This worked for me for a single textview, but when I used it on a linearlayout with multiple textviews, the animated height was larger than the actual wrap_content height! It animated to the over-sized height, then snapped back to the actual height.

Comment: Solved! See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59818318/7812339

Answer (score 7):

An easy solution is to use android:animateLayoutChanges attribute in your layout which includes your component. This is for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN (Android 4.3).
For example, I have one EditText which needs to change from a certain height to wrap_content.

1. Add the android:animateLayoutChanges attribute to my ScrollView.

   ```
     < ScrollView
       ...
       android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
   ```
2. Add this in your onCreateView()

   `scrollView.layoutTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING)`

Then you will see a fairly smooth change of the EditText height.

3. Code to change the height of EditText to wrap_content

   ```
     fun wrapText() {
         val layoutParams = this.layoutParams
         layoutParams.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
         this.layoutParams = layoutParams
         isExpanded = false
     }
   ```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, didn't know this existed! Really helpful answer!