# Android: how to animate height to wrap_content?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

I need to use a ValueAnimator to make a custom "drop field" appear when the user drags a certain view. (I want to change the field from `gone, height = 0` to `visible, height = wrap_content`).

I've tried the solution of this question: [How to animate to wrap_content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55251650/how-to-animate-to-wrap-content)

The answer there worked when I used it on a single TextView, but when I tried to apply it to a LinearLayout with multiple text views it animated to a too large height value, then, when the animation finished, snapped back to the correct one. The layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingVertical="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Using animateLayoutChanges didn't work for me either, and I want to use a custom animator anyway.

I'm using C# in Xamarin, but answering with Android Studio Java code is acceptable too, I'll translate it to C#.

Comment: Keep the height `wrap_content` in xml and then start `valueAnimator` from `0 to initial measured height` programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be caused by measuring the children views during Measure, so you can change your xaml like this ,change your children views's width to `wrap_content`:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="0dp"
  android:visibility="gone"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="5"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingVertical="8dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textSize="18sp"/>
    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="2"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingVertical="8dp"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:textSize="18sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```